# Do we need to remove fabric after migrating the firebase in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

While creating a new project using pod FirebaseCrashlytics, I am able to get new crashes and the existing crash count also increases when same crashes occur.

```
pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics', '4.5.0'
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '6.8.0'
pod 'FirebaseCore', '6.10.1'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '4.6.2'
```

For initializing the crashlytics I have added the script in the build phases:

"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
Input Files:

${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME} $(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)

**NOTE:**

1. While forcing a crash in the existing project that we migrated from Fabric to Firebase, the **crashlytics are not logged, if we removed the fabric functionalities** from the plist/build phase and entire code and followed the above steps.
2. While forcing a crash in the existing project that we migrated from Fabric to Firebase, **the crashlytics are logged, if we are not removing the fabric functionalities** from the plist/build phase and entire code and followed the above steps.

**Is there any additional settings that need to be done so that the crashes are logged in the migrated project itself?**

Comment: Have you included FirebaseApp.configure() in your AppDelegate (or somewhere else)?

Comment: Of course yes.I have included the FirebaseApp.configure() in didFinishLaunchOption in Applegate. I am able to log the crash if we are not removing the functionalities.

Comment: @HarikarthickK What about `GoogleService-Info.plist`?

Comment: I have added the GoogleService-Info.plist as well.

Comment: I have a problem only when I remove the fabric functionalities from the project. Except that all working fine

Comment: What do you mean when you say "removed Fabric functionalities"?

Comment: 1.Removed fabric keys from plist. 2. Modified the build phase like above.

Answer (score 0):

If you have migrated your app from Fabric, you cannot simply delete your Fabric API key and Fabric dependencies, this will cause issues for your app. Make sure you follow [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=ios) entirely for your migrated app, and it should resolve any of your crash reporting issues.

Comment: I have entirely migrated the firebase and followed the firebase integration procedure. But no luck. I have attached the Xcode console logs here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64004154/firebase-verification-that-initialisation-is-not-complete-in-ios-swift

Comment: I would need to see your AppDelegate, but based on that error, it seems like your config statement is off. I recommend creating a fresh test app with minimal activity, making sure you can get it to onboard properly with Crashlytics, and then making sure your current app and your test app have the exact same Crashlytics configuration.