# Firebase verification that initialisation is not complete in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

In our project, we have migrated Fabric to firebase and placed the testing crash “fatalError()” in the button action. The Xcode console print likes below:

```
[Firebase/Crashlytics] Packaged report with id 'c08fc8e4e5a612237324b59f41a4ea5a' for submission
 6.32.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization. 
 6.32.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Unable to read identifier at path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/69232599-CB81-4B49-A560-8932B0553D4A/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.id-pal.app/v5/reports/processing/c08fc8e4e5a612237324b59f41a4ea5a
 6.32.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Failed to move file, inputs invalid
 6.32.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Unable to move report to prepared
```

Also I have created new Project with same bundle id and tried the above steps and I am facing the same logs above and **Firebase that initialisation is not complete.**

[image]

I have followed the firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

**Note: I have tried the same configuration in the new sample app with new login, I am able to see the crashes in firebase dashboard without issue.**

I have enabled the **FIRDebugEnabled** in Xcode and removed the fabric keys from the code base.

POD File installation:

```
Installing Firebase (6.32.2)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (6.8.2)
Installing FirebaseCore (6.10.2)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.6.0)
Installing FirebaseCrashlytics (4.6.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (1.7.0)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (4.6.0)
Installing FirebaseMessaging (4.6.2)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (6.8.2)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (7.3.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (6.7.2)
Installing PromisesObjC (1.2.10)
Installing Protobuf (3.13.0)
Installing nanopb (1.30906.0)
```

Could someone give me some pointers on this?

Answer (score 0):

line 2 mentioned your problem.
add FirebaseApp.configure() to your app delegate in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method
if you did this, please let me know.

Comment: I have added in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function in AppDelegate.

Comment: I have completed all basic integration in migrated app and new sample app. I am facing issue only with the migrated app.

Comment: @HarikarthickK have you 2 plist.info for developing mode and original mode?

Comment: Yes I have created Plist for debug/development and release mode. I have removed the fabric functionalities from the codebase. Is that fine?

Comment: If I use the fabric keys for forcing crash, I am able see the crash. But I want to remove the fabric integration and add the Firebase/Crashlytics.

Comment: @HarikarthickK how can I have contact with you? skype? any social media?